# Error in executing a jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file named- ParseCSV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar and the contents of it are -

- META-INF/
- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
- foo/
- foo/ReadCSV.class
- META-INF/maven/
- META-INF/maven/Test/
- META-INF/maven/Test/ParseCSV/
- META-INF/maven/Test/ParseCSV/pom.xml
- META-INF/maven/Test/ParseCSV/pom.properties

The main class is ReadCSV.class and it takes a CSV file (C:\Testting\ValidaResults.csv) as an input parameter. I am trying to execute the jar file from the command promt by running the following command-

```
java -jar . ParseCSV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "C:\Testting\ValidationResult.csv"
```

But I am getting an error saying-

```
Error: Could not find or load main class foo.ReadCSVTest
```

What is going wrong here.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a . between jar and ParseCSV..?

Try this first:

```
java -jar ParseCSV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "C:\Testting\ValidationResult.csv"
```

If this does not work, then try:

```
java -cp ParseCSV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;. foo.ReadCSV "c:\Testting\ValidationResult.csv"
```

If this works, then i would inspect the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file to figure out what the classpath is like, and what the value of Main-Class is. It seems to be running ReadCSVTest instead of ReadCSV.

Comment: I made a mistake in the pom file and set the main class wrong, hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your JAR file includes foo/ReadCSV.class, but your MainClass is set to foo.ReadCSV**Test**.  You'll need to fix your Main-Class attribute in META-INF/MAINIFEST.MF